# Can Kafka be provided with custom LoginModule to support LDAP?

Tags: apache-kafka, ldap, jaas, sasl

Kafka can be configured to use several authentication mechanisms: plaintext username/password, Kerberos or SSL.  The first 2 use SASL, where there is a JAAS config file required.

For the plain text auth method, the config looks like (taken from the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/sasl.html#kafka-sasl-plain-broker)):

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret"
   user_alice="alice-secret";
};
```

I want to authenticate if possible using LDAP.  My question is this: if I replace the `PlainLoginModule` with a class that implements [LoginModule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/spi/LoginModule.html) and place this class in the broker's classpath, can I implement authentication in any manner I wish (i.e. LDAP)?

I cannot use Kerberos in a reasonable fashion because of the way its principals are defined within the organisation where I'm working, hence I wish to use LDAP as I need to support RBAC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can provide Kafka with a custom class that implements `LoginModule` and have the authentication logic you want in it.

Then update the JAAS file with your class name and make sure it's in the classpath.

You'll need to put some boilerplate code to get everything setup correctly but you can use `PlainLoginModule`, `PlainSaslServerProvider`, `PlainSaslServerFactory` and `PlainSaslServer` as examples.

Your `LoginModule` class should have the same logic as `PlainLoginModule` but instead initialize your `Provider` implementation (in the static block).

Your `Provider` class should have the same logic as `PlainSaslServerProvider` but instead reference your `SaslServerFactory` implementation.

Your `SaslFactory` class should again have the same logic as `PlainSaslServerFactory` but create an instance of your `SaslServer` implementation.

Finally your `SaslServer` class should implement the necessary LDAP logic in its `evaluateResponse()` method. Just be sure to set correctly set `this.authorizationId` as this will become the user principal and set `complete` to `true` (like `PlainSaslServer.evaluateResponse()` does)

Comment: Do you have an example of where this has been done please?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an example I can share but I have added details about how to set everything up. You need to define a few classes but it's mostly scafolding with very little logic.

Comment: Great, thanks - it's good to record that you need to implement all of these classes, not just LoginModule, as I've learned the hard way that PlainSaslServer hard-codes a dependency on PlainLoginModule and you'll get failed authentication errors (without logs, unless you turn on DEBUG, for versions < v1.0).

Comment: @John Confluent Enterprise now has LDAP Authorizer https://docs.confluent.io/current/confluent-security-plugins/kafka/introduction.html