# How to make Kafka plain authentication more secure?

Tags: security, authentication, configuration, ldap, apache-kafka

I am confused about different protocols and mechanisms for Kafka authentication.

Similar to this question here:

[Can Kafka be provided with custom LoginModule to support LDAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295512/can-kafka-be-provided-with-custom-loginmodule-to-support-ldap)

I have kind of made my own PlainLoginModule that uses LDAP to authenticate the username/password provided by the client.

Is there any way for me to make this more secure? It does not seem safe to send plaintext passwords for the authentication. I would also prefer to not use plaintext password in the client side jaas file if possible.

If I were to use SSL could I still use LDAP server to authenticate? How would the kafka configuration change. Current conf:

```
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners = SASL_PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two options how to make it more secure:

- Use SASL_SSL listeners to wrap the SASL authentication into SSL encryption. You will still be able to use your LDAP through custom module.
- Use one of the more secure SASL mechanisms. PLAIN mechanism will send the password over the network which is not secure. You can instead use one of the supported SCRAM mechanisms which will not send the password over the network and will use a more sophisticated handshake instead. Kafka supports SCRAM-SHA-256 and SCRAM-SHA-512. However the SCRAM mechanisms would not work with LDAP - they store the credentials (not directly passwords) in Zookeeper. The SCRAM mechanisms can be of course also combined with SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a SASL_SSL listener. This will use SASL to authenticate and then encrypt the data sent using SSL. If you want more secure authentication, you should consider using the GSSAPI SASL mechanism. ldap and Kerberos integration is a common practice and then you don't have exposed credentials.