# How to authenticate/authorize a consumer in Kafka for a topic before it consumes the message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In kafka, is there a way to authenticate / authorize a consumer every time a consumer tries to read a message on a  topic that it has subscriber to ?

The use case here is that a consumer should be able to present a auth token to the kafka broker and then, broker should be able to validate that token before letting consumer read a message from the topic.

Is the achievable in kafka ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kafka provides both pluggable authentication and authorization mechanisms.

For authentication, the process of creating your own logic is described in:
[Can Kafka be provided with custom LoginModule to support LDAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295512/can-kafka-be-provided-with-custom-loginmodule-to-support-ldap/47295711#47295711)

For authorization, you simply need to provide a class that implements the Authorizer interface (https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/security/auth/Authorizer.scala) and set `authorizer.class.name` to your class in `server.properties`.

Authentication is only performed when a client connects so if you require validation to happen for every consume action, you'll have to use authorizations.

I suggest you get yourself familiar with Kafka security features and more specifically Authorizations: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz